# Unresolved reference R but app builds and run, Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

After I updated the Android studio version, I'm getting `unresolved reference` for every class using `com.package.myapp.R`, can't understand why but the projects build and run normally.

Comment: have you tried reloading the project/IDE, this sounds like a glitch to me, I had this kind of issue too before.

Comment: kotlin or java project?

Comment: @Twometer I already tried the  `Clean` and `Invalidate Caches / Restart`, @navylover the project uses kotlin.

Comment: Happened to me as well. I switched to Android Studio 3.3-beta and now it works...

Comment: @SamuelRobert the latest canary as beta, not the preview?

Comment: AS3.3-beta02 is safe to use

Comment: @SamuelRobert I can't believe it solved, google's so stupid to release so buggy version like that as Stable, thanks.

Comment: I'm sure if AS team had noticed this they would have fixed it right away. I'm not sure what is causing this otherwise would have reported a bug. If you find it please do so

Comment: I suspect it's due to some support libraries conflict.

Comment: For me the problem presented when I enabled the experimental Navigation Editor.